# Error 500 failed to load resource that exists Nginx

Tags: jquery, nginx, internal-server-error

My guess is this is an error with Nginx, but my error logs don't show anything related.

On my page there is an ajax function called:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: "./upload-resize.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
    data: mdata, //Form variables
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response){
        $(".upload-image").hide();
        $(".upload-click").show();

        if (response.type == 'success') {
            $("#server-response").html('<div class="success">' + response.msg + '</div>');
        } else {
            $("#server-response").html('<div class="error">' + response.msg + '</div>');
        }
    }
});
```

The file `upload-resize.php` definitely exists. Chrome's console outputs the following:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) /upload-resize.php:1

But when I click on the upload-resize.php in the inspector, it doesn't give me a 404 or error 500. It goes to the file because it's there.

Any ideas?

My error log is:

```
#0 /var/www/example.com/html/upload-resize.php(49): Imagick->writeimages('/imagemagick_up...', true)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/example.com/html/upload-resize.php on line 49" while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.70.129.98, server: example.com, request: "POST /upload-resize.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/"
```

Line 49 reads:

```
$results = $image->writeImages($upload_dir. $_FILES['image_data']['name'], true);
```

Comment: A 500 error means the PHP code encountered an error. If the file did not exist you would get a 404. So, something in your PHP is not working when you make the Ajax call. What do you get in your php logs?

Comment: Thanks! Updated my question

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier - what does your NGINX conf look like? You may need to add some lines to help with uploading files.